# Comparing 2 Data Frames and making a new one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 data frames `df1` and `df2` with one column each. I want to compare them row by row, and if the values in the columns match make a new data frame with all the matched values. If not make a data frame with 2 columns for unmatched values.

```
equal_index = []
equal_df1 = []
not_equal_index = []
not_equal_df1 = []
not_equal_df2 = []

for x in df1.index.tolist():
    if df1['column'].ix[x] == df2['column'].ix[x]:
        equal_index.append(x)
        equal_df1.append(df1['column'].ix[x])
    else:
        not_equal_index.append(x)
        not_equal_df1.append(df1['column'].ix[x])
        not_equal_df2.append(df2['column'].ix[x])

DF_equal = pd.DataFrame({"column":equal_df1}, index = equal_index )
DF_not_equal = pd.DataFrame({'column1':not_equal_df1,'column2':not_equal_df2}, index = not_equal_index)
```

It seems like it should be working but I get an error: `ValueError: the truth value of a Series is ambiguous.`

Also if I try something basic

```
for x in df1.index.tolist():
    print df1['column'].ix[x] == df2['column'].ix[x]
```

I get `True` or `False` for as many x's as I have

If I use `is` instead of `==` I get all the values in the `DF_not_equal`.

Comment: Try it now, i didn't use `loc` for the the `append` earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({0:['test','test2','test3'], 1:['foo','foo2','foo3'], 2:['bar','bar2', 'bar3']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({0:['test','test2','test4'], 1:['foo','foo2','foo3'], 2:['bar','bar2', 'bar3']})

df_equal = pd.DataFrame()

df_not_equal = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    if all(df.loc[i].values==df2.loc[i].values):
        df_equal = df_equal.append(df.loc[i], ignore_index=True)
    else:
        df_not_equal['A'] = df.loc[i]
        df_not_equal['B'] = df2.loc[i]

print(df_equal)

print(df_not_equal)
```

Will give you:

```
       0     1     2
0   test   foo   bar
1  test2  foo2  bar2
       A      B
0  test3  test4
1   foo3   foo3
2   bar3   bar3
```

Looking at the error you provided, the problem lies in `if df1['column'].ix[x] == df2['column'].ix[x]:`. `pandas` does not allow such type of comparison, that's why they said "ambiguous".

The issue is fixed by using the actual values of the row, and you need to either check for `all` or `any` (those are self explanatory I hope).

Comment: I want my `df_not_equal` to have columns from both dataframes. Now it just appends extra rows. But `df_equal` works correctly.
But I still can't figure out what was wrong with my code